# Send HTTP status code to both write-console AND clipboard

Tags: powershell

I have a small PowerShell script which I need to send the HTTP status code to both write-console AND Windows Clipboard.  Currently, I can send the HTTP status code to the console (write-console) but not also to the clipboard (at the same time).  I have a very specific corner case scenario in which I need to send the status code to both places.  The working example below sends the status code to console only.  By editing, I can send the status code to Clipboard instead, but then it won't go to the console.  It seems PowerShell will let you send to one or the other but not to both simultaneously.  Note:  example.com is not the actual URL I am working with, nor the API key.

```
#####################
#requires -Version 5
#requires -PSEdition Desktop

class TrustAllCertsPolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
    [bool] CheckValidationResult([System.Net.ServicePoint] $a,
                                 [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate] $b,
                                 [System.Net.WebRequest] $c,
                                 [int] $d) {
        return $true
    }
}
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = [TrustAllCertsPolicy]::new()

$apiKey = "1HuDSkiLXFwib2FqJ88mgtfd1mMpaJoR"
$url = "http://www.example.com"
$header = @{"USPTO-API-KEY" = $apiKey}

#Tries 10 times: 
# $i=1; while($i -lt 10){Try{(Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $header).StatusCode}catch{Write-Host($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__)}  ;$i++}

#This would be even better.  It tests until it gets something other than a 200 or hits a maximum;
$i=1
Do{
 Try{$SC=(Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $header).StatusCode}
 catch{$SC=($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__)}
 Write-host($SC)
 $i++}
 Until($SC -ne 200 -or $i -gt 10)
  
######## END ################
```

Comment: Why to the clipboard vs a file? I am assuming you are just going to save that anyways. Lastly, there are several ways to save results or a variable, and output to the screen at the same time. What `Michal Rosenbaum` is a way, here are a few more, eliminating the need for Write-* stuff, if you are putting to the screen always: [3 ways to store and display PowerShell Variable simultaneously](https://ridicurious.com/2017/06/30/3-ways-to-store-display-results-infrom-a-powershell-variable-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to save to a file - as this PowerShell script is nested inside of another program which saves the result to a file in order to keep it consistent with the other operations that run asynchronously which all ultimately log to that single file.  Those operation run outside of PowerShell, some run in JavaScript, and others in other languages....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your script, added a variable for clipboard `$clipboard` which I'm populating with `$SC` in your loop and at the end of the script I added `Set-CLipboard $clipboard` and after it finishes I've got everything both in my clipboard and out in the console.

```
$apiKey = "1HuDSkiLXFwib2FqJ88mgtfd1mMpaJoR"
$url = "http://www.example.com"
$header = @{"USPTO-API-KEY" = $apiKey}

$clipboard = "";
#Tries 10 times: 
# $i=1; while($i -lt 10){Try{(Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $header).StatusCode}catch{Write-Host($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__)}  ;$i++}

#This would be even better.  It tests until it gets something other than a 200 or hits a maximum;
$i=1
Do{
 Try{$SC=(Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $header).StatusCode}
 catch{$SC=($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__)}
 Write-host($SC)
 $clipboard += $SC
 $i++}
 Until($SC -ne 200 -or $i -gt 10)
  
Set-Clipboard $clipboard
```

Even when I'm doing `Set-Clipboard $SC` inside the loop, after the execution I've got one occurrence of 200 in my clipboard and console full of 200s

Answer (score 1):

Using '+=' copies the variable, adds the new item, and saves the old variable.  With large variables it can add up.  My preferred way is with a list:

$clipboard = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]
$clipboard.Add($SC)
...
Set-Clipboard $clipboard